# Sports data set. Olympics. High jump

Tags: data-request, sports

I am seeking, but have been unable to find, detailed information about the women's high jump at the 2020 Tokyo Olympics (which was of course held in 2021). I particularly want data about the sequence in which the athletes jumped (but not necessarily time-stamped) including whether an athlete chose not to try a particular height, as well information about as success or failure. I had hoped that the Olympics site itself would have the information but I was surprised to find that it does not. In the absence of anything else, I would be willing to watch the entirety of the replays but I have been unable to find the videos for the qualifying events.

Answer (score 2):

Scorecard PDFs are available on the world athletics website if you click official results -> download: https://www.worldathletics.org/results/olympic-games/2021/the-xxxii-olympic-games-athletics-7132391/women/high-jump/qualification/series

And for the final: https://www.worldathletics.org/results/olympic-games/2021/the-xxxii-olympic-games-athletics-7132391/women/high-jump/final/series#resultheader

If you click "startlist" you can see the seeding order as well, the order of jumps would follow that skipping people who have dropped out or passed

You can watch the full session replays for free if you have a Japanese VPN but if you're in the US I think you may have to pay for Peacock / NBC Sports to see the VODs as they have exclusive rights.